# Pyside6 QLineEdit bug with a particular sequence of input characters

Tags: python, qlineedit, pyside6

When I run the following code :

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.textChanged.connect(self.print_textChanged)
        self.le.textEdited.connect(self.print_textEdited)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Get text")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.get_text)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
  
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def print_textChanged(self, text):
        print(f"textChanged : {text}")

    def print_textEdited(self, text):
        print(f"textEdited : {text}")

    def get_text(self):
        print(f"QLineEdit.text() = {self.le.text()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

and enter this sequence of text in the input field with my laptop keyboard :
@JohnDoe@987@

a new character is inserted at the end. It seems like this solo-added character is depending on the digits before the last '@' character.

If I delete the string and retype it again, this new character won't appear.
I need to restart python script to get this strange behavior again.

If I change the sequence numbers (e.g. 985 instead of 987), I get a different character inserted.
Here are 4 tests for you to see what I mean (of course I stopped pressing the keyboard on last '@' character) :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is happening ? Are there any special sequences in my test string ?

This is the end of the output when I only pressed the keys '7' and '@' (with alt gr + 0 combination) :
[image]
OS : Windows 10 21H2
Computer : Dell Precision 3561, AZERTY classic layout
PySide6 version : 6.4.0
No keyboard or shortcut manager

Thank you

PS : I tried with PyCharm IDE and with command line, same behavior.

Comment: what OS are you using

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: We need more specific details: actual OS version, Qt and PyQt version, if you're using a special input method (screen keyboard, odd keyboard layout or other non-latin inputs). It's also not clear what is the "new character" you're referring to.

Comment: I added requested details in edited post.

Comment: And what is that character? Can you provide some screenshots/video? Also, does the new text reflect in the `text` property of the line edit? Try connecting the `textChanged` *and* `textEdited` signals to a function that prints out both the argument value of the signal *and* the `text` property. Eventually considering using a subclass and override the `keyPressEvent` to see the actual keyboard events received. Also, I suppose you're using a french keyboard layout, are you typing the "@" using AltGr-0 or in other ways? Do you have some keyboard/shortcut manager?

Comment: I edited the post once more to give you more details.

Comment: 9792 is the unicode point for  9792 ♀  and 9496 is 9496 ┘ .... I am assuming you have something installed that you aren't aware of or have some feature for some program that is outputing unicode characters with certain key combinations and key strokes

Comment: On my UK keyboard, if I type Alt+12 I get a ♀ character. Alt+985 gives me ┘ and Alt+987 █. These are characters 12, 217 (=985 % 256, also 0xD9) and 219 (=987 % 256, also 0xDB) in code page 850 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).