# Pyside6 QLineEdit uknown empty char

Tags: python, pyside6, qlineedit

I've got a strange behavior in Python/Pyside6 QLineEdit.

Is there any ASCII char combination that QLineEdit.setText() will interpret as possible empty char ?

Could not replicate on a second run (happened only on 1 run instance a couple of times) It is also connected to random string generation (so not easy to replicate).

What I did was rand string from azAZ0-9 plus only one from a few punctuations !#$*+-.<=>@_

On on one instance I got a string that had empty space in between, something like:

> AqApUn +AgAveh

I tried to copy it from QLineEdit to notepad++ to see what is it but was unable to copy - got only the first part "AqApUn" in clipboard.

My app saves the string to a DB. I closed it and rerun - and ... it only loaded the first part AqApUn only - so it seems the empty char in QLineEdit was kind of escape char?

Checked the doc and QLineEdit should not allow any Rich Text formats, plus I was not generating rich text and used only few punctuations.

Tried to do few rand cycles using + or $ or # punctuations only but could not replicate.

Sounds like a hard to reproduce /SCARY / bug. If anyone familiar with deep Python guts or Pyside6 have any idea how come such a thing can happen - let me know.

My setup is Win10, Python 3.11

The bug is somewhat similar to this one, but Im not typing the chars manually, auto generated, so no reason to get "alt+" char in there:

[Pyside6 QLineEdit bug with a particular sequence of input characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74205763/pyside6-qlineedit-bug-with-a-particular-sequence-of-input-characters)

Tried to debug doing different rand cycles

Comment: How are you creating that string and the space? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it in another run of the app. Tried about 10 session for total ~100 runs. String production is probably unrelated - otherwise it would happen in another app run (but only happened in one session ***few times!***). I'm expecting rather theoretical answers, most likely QT, less likely Python core bug. 1. Why copy to clipboard was not possible (only the part of string before white space was possibly to copy - which indicates this is likely QLineEdit bug.  2. how come setText() produce empty char inside QLineEdit, where there was no such option to get empty string.

Comment: This is a nightmare not be able to reproduce the bug and suggests QT is not reliable/ for unknown reasons (bad initialization on some occasions?) sets wrong strings in QLineEdit and not allow to copy the whole thing. The process: click button to generate string and set it via setText is rather simple and basic... The QLineEdit didn't have validatior or mask, I just click button to get new one. And the orig string was generated from non-empty chars :/

Comment: Just tried to "force" the example by incorporating space " " into the punctuation set, but this does not reproduce the part where I'm unable to copy full string to clipboard, meaning - when I add space to string purposefully I can copy the full string from QLineEdit, so the bug is not about a regular whitespace, but some kind of strange escape char that is even blocking ctrl+c

Comment: Decided to report a bug on QT site. Even if we assume I badly generated string this does not explain why I was not able to copy it whole from QLineEdit by selecting and ctrl+c. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2378

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this is too much malloc-like bug hence ther otehr lib I used is probably messing Python memory.
I used pysecmem module which is suppose to clear string/bytes from memory and overwrite them with some \0.
I have no proof (as malloc errors are not easy to replicate) but at this moment I believe this experimenta/unsafe/"forbiden" module is most probable cause of this behaviour.

Not sure what to do with the orig post - should be delete or edited?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).